# Discord Bot Setup Command, save message after different message

Tags: javascript, installation, discord, bots

I want to make a setup, where the user first types a command (which I already did), in my case `.create`. After that command the user should give something a name with `.create (name)`. Has anybody an idea of how I can do that? Here is my code, that I have to that command yet:

````
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content == ".create") {
         const create = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
           .setColor('#000033')
           .setTitle('```Create Achievement```')
           .setDescription("Step 1 of 5")
           .addFields(
              { name: 'Choose a name', value: 'In this step you will have to choose a name for your new achievement' },
              { name: '.create (name)', value: 'Type `.create (name)` in the chat to give the achievement a name.' },
           )
           .setTimestamp()
           .setFooter(message.author.username);

        message.channel.send(create)
        console.log(message.member.user.tag +' executed command .CREATE')
    }
})
````

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit evil to let people wonder how to handle these things properly, commands made simple with no extra advice.

```js
function Check(receivedMessage) {
    var splitCommand = receivedMessage.substr(1).split(/\s+/);
    // Command Check
    try {
        if (typeof PublicCommands[splitCommand[0]] == "function") {
            PublicCommands[splitCommand[0]](splitCommand.slice(1), receivedMessage);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("ERROR", e);
    }
}
let PublicCommands = {
    "something": (args, receivedMessage) => {
        console.log(args);
        if (args.includes("like")) {
          console.log("we may have a taker");
        }
    }
};
Check(".something like this?");

// This example is very basic but very powerful. Enjoy.
```

Comment: The beautiful thing here is the time it takes to recognize a command!

Comment: Does this "save" the answer?

Comment: This is simple command determining, you can set it up to take .create My Name. This could be saved however you wish to save it, that's up to you!

Comment: If means are to make this a bit more advanced as in keep track of a users response, you just store their responses in an array or something and determine if they can move along to your next-steps.